# How to restart PHP-FPM from cron?

Tags: cron, php-fpm

I'm trying to restart PHP5-FPM periodically using Cron, but am having no luck.

I can restart manually with no problems, using `service php5-fpm restart` or `/usr/sbin/service php5-fpm restart`

However, when I use the same command, including using the full path to `/usr/sbin/service`, nothing happens. The cronjob does run (as I see from the syslog), but PHP5-FPM does not restart.

The relevant line of my root user's crontab looks as follows:

```
* * * * * /usr/sbin/service php5-fpm restart
```

I have confirmed with `which service` that the path to service is indeed `/usr/sbin/service`.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Does the user running the cron job receive mail when it runs? (check in /var/mail if you haven't configured forwarding)

Comment: Why would you want to restart php-fpm every minute?

Comment: Same with me. 'service' just does not work from cron and no idea how to debug

Comment: Why would you want to restart php-fpm _at all_?

Comment: Do you use it /etc/crontab or in /etc/cron.d/ ?

Comment: Try to export PATH before /usr/sbin/service call. /usr/sbin/service is just a script and it use a environment PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `initctl`:

```
/sbin/initctl  restart php5-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Late to the party answer</sup>

`cron` runs scripts in a very light environment.

`service` does indeed check if the service is an *init upstart* or an */etc/init.d* script, and in this case will run the

```
[ /sbin/ ] restart
```

command (a symlink to *initctl*) but it fails because the `/sbin` path is not part of the `PATH` when *cron* runs and `restart` is given without its absolute path.

You could actually [set the PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user) for *cron* at the beginning of the *crontab*, but it is better to set directly the command in need as

```
m h * * * /sbin/restart php5-fpm
```

---

<sup>**Note**</sup>
 use the symlink */sbin/restart* instead of calling directly *initctl*. The scripts/commands are here for a reason, basically to help the administrator with commands doing something specific, a simple syntax, and having a name easy to remember.

Today `restart` is a symlink. Tomorrow it may become a script doing some other things before calling `initctl`.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I can come up with is to comment out following lines in /etc/init.d/php5-fpm file:

```
# Don't run if we are running upstart
#if init_is_upstart; then
#    exit 1
#fi
```

Comment: That's not weird, that's correct.  `if a; then b; fi` says to execute b (in this case, `exit 1`) if and only if a is true (in this case, `init_is_upstart` returns success, ie 0).

Comment: yep, you are right. Makes sense. Never the less, it does not explain why "service php5-fpm restart" does not work from cron script and works from console though init_is_upstart returns 0.

Comment: Indeed not, though I didn't claim that the reverse of your answer explained the phenomenon: only that yours didn't!  I suspect, from that test, that the whole problem has something to do with upstart, and the way that old-style SYSV init scripts are at best imperfectly supported under the new regimes (upstart, systemd). Since I don't use any new-style systmes for production work (it's been one of the main reasons I haven't moved my C6 systems to C7) I'm afraid I can't shed any light on it.